# Hyperledger composer performance(adding asset) is very low

Tags: performance, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Following code is simple code to check how many entities can be added per second or minute. 
createAsset is calling backend(http:localhost:3000) and add data using post.

When I did test using this code, it took 23 seconds to add 10 entities.

I am using composer 0.19.12 and fabric 1.1. When I checked some thread from GitHub, performance has improved using indexing couchdb. How can I use that feature? (I need to check again, but it seems that it is default feature of recent composer version)

```
addEntities: async function() {

    var start = 0;
    var end = start + 100;
    var sd = new Date();
    console.log(sd.getHours()+':'+sd.getMinutes()+':'+sd.getSeconds()+'.'+sd.getMilliseconds());

    for(var i = start; i<end; i++) {
        entityData.id = i.toString();
        await this.createAsset('/Entity', 'model.Entity', entityData);
    }

    var ed = new Date();
    var totalTime = new Date(ed.getTime()-sd.getTime());
    console.log(totalTime.getMinutes()+':'+totalTime.getSeconds()+'.'+totalTime.getMilliseconds());
},
```

My model is really simple as follows.

```
asset Entity identified by id {
  o String id
}
```

---

I have changed the test code to send multiple transactions as follows following david_k's advice.

```
addEntities: async function() {

        var start = 15000;
        var dataNumber = 1200;
        var loopNumber = 400;
        var end = start + dataNumber;
        var sd = new Date();
        console.log(sd.getHours()+':'+sd.getMinutes()+':'+sd.getSeconds()+'.'+sd.getMilliseconds());

        var tasks = [];
        for(var i = start; i<end; i++) {
            entityData.id = i.toString();

            if((i-start)%loopNumber === loopNumber - 1) {
                await this.createAsset('/Entity', 'model.Entity', entityData);
                console.log('--- i: ' + i + ' loops completed');
            }
            else {
                this.createAsset('/Entity', 'model.Entity', entityData);
            }
        }
        var ed = new Date();
        var totalTime = new Date(ed.getTime()-sd.getTime());
        console.log(totalTime.getMinutes()+':'+totalTime.getSeconds()+'.'+totalTime.getMilliseconds());
    },
```

The purpose of change is send multiple requests at the same time, and it seems work well because it shows much better performance compared to previous code. However, the performance is still around 8 TPS. As original test code was 1 transaction per 2sec~3sec, it improved a lot. But, 8TPS looks that it cannot be used for commercial application at all. Even it is not good for test purpose as well. Could someone give some advice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds about right looking at your example code and I am assuming you are using either the fabric-dev-servers package which is a very simple fabric network to help get users started with developing a business network and want to try out on a hyperledger fabric network, or you are using the byfn network from the multi-org tutorial which is a hyperledger fabric example of a 2 organisation network in a consortium to demonstrate the required operational steps of composer in a multi-org fabric setup.

Hyperledger Fabric is a distributed ledger technology based around eventual consistency. Composer implements a submit/notify model such that once a transaction has been submitted it will notify the client when that transaction has been committed to the ledger. You can configure which Peers in a network you are interested in informing you when that occurs, but the default is all of them and so the rest server responds once all peers have committed it to the ledger.

Hyperledger fabric doesn't commit individual transactions, it batches them up into blocks and these blocks get committed to the ledger, and it will wait a period of time before building that block with the current set of transactions that have been submitted for ordering, so blocks can contain one or more transactions. You need to configure fabric for your use case to determine how transactions are batched into blocks.

Comment: It is good to understand. Here is my understanding. My current code is writing one transaction per block as await function call is waiting until all peer nodes update the ledger. Is this correct? I would like to give you point but my level is too low. Then, how to improve the performance to add asset for example? how could I know maximum number of transaction per block?